# multiple indexes in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

As per my requirement, I have to show seven days data to the customer in each day tabbed view and each day data is different from other day data like price/quantity_in_hand etc. Following is a sample for 1 day. The same SKU will be repeated with different qty/price and available data.

My question is that, do I need to create an index for each day in advance because each day data is getting change or is there any other way to do it efficiently.

```
    "sku": [
    {
        "storeId": 10101,
        "storeName": "Store-1",
        "skuId": 10142,
        "skuName": "SkuName1",
        "storeSalePrice": 10.0,
        "currencySymobol": "$",
        "minQTY": 1,
        "maxQty": 1000,
        "description": "QWERTYUIOP{",
        "productId": 10142,
        "longDescription": "QWERTYUIOPOUYSDFGHJKXCVBNMDFGHJXGHJXCVBNM",
        "location": {
            "lat": 37.565359,
            "lon": -122.042346
        },
        "categoryTypeName": "categoryTypeName",
        "skuSearchKeyWords": "LKJKL,SDFDSF,ERWER,SDFDSF,AFAF,AF,DF,ASDF",
        "skuAvailabilityDate": "2018-01-02"
    },
    {
        "storeId": 10101,
        "storeName": "Store-1",
        "skuId": 10142,
        "skuName": "SkuName1",
        "storeSalePrice": 10.0,
        "currencySymobol": "$",
        "minQTY": 1,
        "maxQty": 1000,
        "description": "QWERTYUIOP{",
        "productId": 10142,
        "longDescription": "QWERTYUIOPOUYSDFGHJKXCVBNMDFGHJXGHJXCVBNM",
        "location": {
            "lat": 37.565359,
            "lon": -122.042346
        },
        "categoryTypeName": "categoryTypeName",
        "skuSearchKeyWords": "LKJKL,SDFDSF,ERWER,SDFDSF,AFAF,AF,DF,ASDF",
        "skuAvailabilityDate": "2018-01-02"

    }
]
```

Comment: I think you need to add some timestamp field and then you can use DateHistogram aggregation..

Answer (score 0):

you can create template with the index name pattern , then first inserted document to a new day will create the index with the schema according to the template.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Comment: I tried that but template did not apply. I got these logs after inserting a record. 
 [lmc_es_clustor_node1] [lmc_date_idx_sku-2018-01-02] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []

Comment: I have put template definition at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371891/templateis-not-applying-in-elasticsearch-index